# Add SubView (WebView) within NSView subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

OK, the scenario is pretty straightforward, but - since `NSView`s have never been my strongest point - I decided to ask for some help.

So...

- We have an `NSView` subclass
- When the `NSView` is created, we want to add a subview (`WebView`) which is going to occupy all the initial view's space + automatically resize in width/height.

**And this is my code** *(which still does not work, as described)* :

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {

    NSLog(@"In INIT");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self == nil) return nil;

    [self setWebView:[[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]];
    [[self webView] setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                                     ofType:@"html"];

    NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path     
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                         error:nil];

    [[[self webView] mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlContent 
                                       baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

    [self addSubview:[self webView]];

    return self;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the question?